# check if specific cells in Excel have data or not C#

Tags: c#, excel, ado.net

when I import Excel file to database I want to check if cells[1000,1000] have data or not but don't insert it to database I use this code to insert data to database using ADO.net and C#:

```
DataTable table1 = result1.Tables[1];
for (int i = 1; i < table1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    DataRow row = table1.Rows[i];
    string input = Convert.ToString(row[0]);
    var reg = new Regex(pattern2, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    Match match = reg.Match(input);

    string input2 = Convert.ToString(row[1]);
    var reg2 = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    Match match2 = reg2.Match(input2);

    string input3 = Convert.ToString(row[2]);
    var reg3 = new Regex(Num, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    Match match3 = reg3.Match(input3);

    string input4 = Convert.ToString(row[3]);
    var reg4 = new Regex(Num, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    Match match4 = reg4.Match(input4);

    string input5 = Convert.ToString(row[4]);
    var reg5 = new Regex(Num, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    Match match5 = reg5.Match(input5);

    string input6 = Convert.ToString(row[5]);
    var reg6 = new Regex(Email, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    Match match6 = reg4.Match(input6);

    Banks ba = new Banks();

    if (match.Success && match2.Success && match3.Success)
    {
        ba.NCode = Convert.ToString(row[0]);
        ba.Nname = Convert.ToString(row[1]);
        ba.NTel1 = Convert.ToString(row[2]);
        if ( match4.Success || String.IsNullOrEmpty(row[3].ToString()))
            ba.NTel2 = Convert.ToString(row[3]);


        if (match5.Success || String.IsNullOrEmpty(row[4].ToString()))
            ba.NFax = Convert.ToString(row[4]);

        if (match6.Success || String.IsNullOrEmpty(row[5].ToString()))
            ba.NEmail = Convert.ToString(row[5]);


        ba.NAdd = Convert.ToString(row[6]);
        ba.NCntPer = Convert.ToString(row[7]);
        if (ValidateNewBank(ba))
        {
            ba.InsertRow();
            counts++;
        }

    }



}

excelreader1.Close();
stream1.Close();
```

notice:I Want to check if data is 1002 or not if not don't but data to database

Comment: Where is the problem? Have you checked which content they have when you don't want to add it to the database? Maybe `string.Empty` or `null`? Why not using a simple `if` statement?

Comment: the problem is i don't know how to select specific cell and i don't know know to not  insert it to database